# Get wordpress post publish date in format 2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get WordPress post publish date in the format,

```
2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00
```

I have tried,

```
 <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
```

But it shows date in different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the format you want when you call the [get_the_date()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) function.
For the ISO format you want you need 'c', like this:

`get_the_date('c')` will print the format your looking for.

Go to the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) if you want to read more on date and time formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings -> General**, in **Date Format** section select `Custom:` and write `c` in text input. Save Changes!